# How can I insert into a table related data in other tables using stored procedure and transaction?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-normalization, database-cursor

I've got a table that has been imported into the database. This table has a series of user-friendly data as it comes from an Excel template that is exported to CSV then imported into a table.
In an oversimplified example, I've got the following:

```
MYDB.CSV
+----------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| language | item               | title            | description                         |
+----------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Spanish  | Grandioso Artículo | Gran Título      | Este es un ejemplo en español.      |
| English  | Powerful Item      | Power Title      | This is an example in english.      |
| French   | Incroyable Article | Incroyable Titre | Ceci est un exemple en français.    |
| English  | Dull Item          | Dull Title       | This is another example in english. |
+----------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

The data of these columns belong to different tables that contain more related characteristics, like these:

```
MYDB.LANGUAGES
 ════╤════════════════════ 
  id │ code   description  
 ────┼──────────────────── 
  1  │ eng    English      
  2  │ spa    Spanish      
  3  │ fra    French       
 ════╧════════════════════ 

MYDB.ITEMS
 ════╤═══════════════════════════════ 
  id │ code       description         
 ────┼─────────────────────────────── 
  1  │ dull-789   Dull Item           
  2  │ incr-456   Incroyable Article  
  3  │ gran-123   Grandioso Artículo  
  4  │ powe-951   Powerful Item       
 ════╧═══════════════════════════════
```

**How can I get related data to the `mydb.csv` columns to be able to insert it into another table using a stored procedure?** I'm trying to get something like this:

```
MYDB.NICETABLE

  id │ code   description   title             
 ════╪═══════════════════════════════════════ 
  1  │ spa    gran-123      Gran Título       
  2  │ eng    powe-951      Powerful Item     
  3  │ fra    incr-456      Incroyable Titre  
  4  │ eng    dull-789      Dull Title
```

I've tried the following code in a stored procedure. The data that has to be inserted as is, like `csv.title` in this example, I can insert it::

```
DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addItems //
    CREATE PROCEDURE addItems ()

    BEGIN
        START TRANSACTION;
            /* INSERT INTO the corresponding tables */
            INSERT INTO mydb.nicetable (title) 
                SELECT `title` FROM csv;
        COMMIT;
    END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL addBrand();
```

How do I compare row by row data (i.e. `csv.language`) and get what I need (i.e. `languages.code`) and insert it into another table (i.e. `nicetable.code`)?

Comment: "get related data to the mydb.csv columns to be able to insert it into another table using a stored proedure" Athough we can figure out what you probably mean, this is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. [mre]

Comment: @philipxy I understand however I had a difficult time trying to express myself correctly, so I understand I didn't choose the best words. Can you suggest an edit? About the example, I gave one in it's simplest form: I didn't need to fuss away what I meant with unnecessary code.

Comment: I suggest again that you try to do the things I just suggested in my 1st comment. You really seem to not have actually tried to be clear. And now I will leave another comment I leave all the time.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SELECT is like any query and follow the same rules.

In your case you make a subselct in languages

If you need data from other tables, you need to join them.

```
DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addItems //
    CREATE PROCEDURE addItems ()

    BEGIN
        START TRANSACTION;
            /* INSERT INTO the corresponding tables */
            INSERT INTO mydb.nicetable (code   ,title) 
                SELECT (SELECT `code`  FROM LANGUAGES LS WHERE LS.description   = c.language LIMIT 1), c.`title` FROM csv c;
        COMMIT;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have used subqueries before, yet I haven't used them this way. Specially the part where the `csv` table is not present in the statement between parenthesis (I'd see it as "incomplete" if it was all alone)  Thanks for your kind help.